# Finding capped memory of a non global zone

Tags: solaris, zones

Is there a way to find the capped memory of a solaris non global zone from the non global zone itself (given rcapd is disabled)

Answer (score 1):

To get capped-memory swap limit from non-global-zone:

```
$ /usr/bin/prctl -n zone.max-swap $$
process: 222852: -bash
NAME    PRIVILEGE       VALUE    FLAG   ACTION                           RECIPIENT
zone.max-swap
        usage           8.22GB   
        privileged      16.0GB      -   deny                                     -
        system          16.0EB    max   deny                                 -
```

Limited value is 'privileged' line. If this limit is not set, then we get 16.0EB.

To get capped-memory physical limit from non-global-zone:

```
$ /usr/sbin/prtconf
System Configuration:  Oracle Corporation  sun4v
Memory size: 112640 Megabytes
System Peripherals (Software Nodes):

prtconf: devinfo facility not available
```

If this limit is not set, then we get global zone physical memory value.

To get capped-memory locked from non-global-zone:

```
/usr/bin/prctl -n zone.max-locked-memory $$
```